# Check out to document owner using powershell

Tags: document-library, powershell, check-out

I have a document library with 200 + documents.  I would like to check out all documents in the library to the document owner.  I have seen a few powershell scripts that check in documents but not out.  Has anyone had any experience of this?

Also is there a way to automatically checkout the document when uploaded to the library?

Answer (score 1):

Automatic check out can be done by ItemEventReceiver on ItemAdded event: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

if you saw the scripts for check in, it is similar to check out. You just have to run the script under the user to whom should be the files checked out or you can impersonate:

```
$user=$web.AllUsers.GetByID(1073741823);
$token = $user.UserToken;
$impWebObj = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($web.Url, $token);
$imperWeb = $impWebObj.OpenWeb();
$list = $imperWeb.Lists["My List"]

# do the checkout for all files in library
$list.Items | % { $_.File.Checkout() }
$imperWeb.Close();
```

http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.de/2011/04/powershell-and-sharepoint-impersonation.html